# cluster analysis with weight

Tags: r, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have a data frame 'heat' demonstrating people's performance across time.

'Var1' represents the code of persons.

'Var2' represents a time line (measured by number of days from the starting point).

'Variable' is the score they get at a given time point.

```
     Var1       Var2      value
1       1   36       -0.6941826
2       2   36       -0.5585414
3       3   36        0.8032384
4       4   36        0.7973031
5       5   36        0.7536959
6       6   36       -0.5942059
  ....
54     10   73        0.7063218
55     11   73       -0.6949616
56     12   73       -0.6641516
57     13   73        0.6890433
58     14   73        0.6310124
59     15   73       -0.6305091
60     16   73        0.6809655
61     17   73        0.8957870
  ....
101    13  110        0.6495796
102    14  110        0.5990869
103    15  110       -0.6210600
104    16  110        0.6441960
105    17  110        0.7838654
  ....
```

Now I want to cluster their performance and reflect it on a heatmap. So I used the function dist() and hclust() to clustered the data frame and plotted it with ggplot2:

```
ggplot(data = heat) + geom_tile(aes(x = Var2, y = Var1 %>% as.character(), 
fill = value)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "yellow",high = "red") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(746, 2142, 2917))
```

It looks like this:[image]

However, I am more interested in what happened around day 746, day 2142 and day 2917 (the black lines). I would like the scores around these days bearing more weight in the clustering. I want people demonstrating similar performance around these days to have more priority to be clustered together. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

As long as your weights are integer, you supposedly can just replicate those days artificially.

If you want more control, just compute the distance matrix yourself, with whatever weighted distance you want to use.